# Got "Can't open __builtin__ module" error when using jump-to-definition within emacs

Tags: python, emacs, spacemacs

I enabled python layer in spacemacs, and when using jump-to-definition, I got "Can't open `__builtin__` module" error.
I used the same vim style command "gd" in pycharm, and got no problem.
Not sure if I configured anything wrong or it is a bug?

Comment: I was going to add an answer with the results of a few discussions on github, but just realized that all these discussions where issues raised by you recently. I would suggest that you answer this question yourself with a summary of what you have learned from these github issues.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, let's close the loop on this one.
I believe the OP eventually [opened a bug](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7435) against spacemacs.
The bug escalated [to the bug queue](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode/issues/205) of the anaconda project, where it was ruled as "not a bug - expected behaviour".

Long story short, this behaviour would happen, for instance, when trying to `jump-to-definition` of a method decorated with `classmethod`.

However, I personally can't reproduce it - so maybe it's been fixed ever since?